# Can't seem to get bridge edge loops to work properly in blender

Tags: edges

Can't seem to get bridge edge loops to work properly in blender. I'm completely new to blender. this is a shot of what I get. Please help.[image]

Comment: I don't see how that geometry could be used in bridging edge loops or alike, it's too uneven and unnecessary complex. It would clear things up a bit if you show what you have before bridging, maybe there's a simple way.

Comment: Welcome, Mario Jones. You can't bridge a loop to itself. I suggest you read the Blender manual showing the way you should use it. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html

Comment: Please share the blend file here. I'll take a look.You can do this by uploading the blend file on this site - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and copy + pasting the generated url here.

Comment: Try just pressing F,